# Problems converting float to int in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm trying to sum the values inside a vector by using a function that must to return a float value, like this:

```
float vectorSum(float *vector, int vectorSize){
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vectorSize; i++){
        cout << vector[i] << "\n";
        resultado += vetor[i];
    }
    cout << "\n\n";

    return resultado;
}
```

Than I have this vars that will be filled by the user:

```
float vector[0];
int vectorSize;


cout << "Write the " << vectorSize << " values to insert in the vector:" << endl;

    for (int c = 0; c < vectorSize; c++){
        cin >> vector[c];
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
```

And finally will call the function vectorSum:

```
cout << "The sum of the vector's values is:" << endl;
    vectorSumTotal = vectorSum(vector, vectorSize);
    cout << vectorSumTotal;
    cout << "\n\n";
```

THE PROBLEM:

If I fill the vectorSize with the value 3 and fill the vector with the values: 1, 2, 6

Than, I don't know why, the 6 become 8.40779e-45 and I need it to keep the value 6.

Is it a problem with conversion of float to int or maybe the pointer?

Help?

Comment: `float vector[0];` is fixed-size array. Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **never** initialize memory for the `vector`. You'll have to do `float *vector = new float[vectorSize];` and only then fill it with values (and then `delete[] vector;`)

Also, why are you using an array of `float`s while there's `std::vector` that is a better choice in your situation.

What's more, avoid calling your array `vector` since there exists `std::vector`, and if you'll be using `using namespace std;` you'll shadow it.

Comment: "you'll shadow it" -- that is, **dont** use `using namespace std;`. That's why namespaces were invented.

Comment: @PeteBecker, agreed, but still, calling a variable `vector` _may_ cause some confusion with `std::vector` despite it's in another namespace.

Comment: "Also, why are you using an array of floats while there's std::vector that is a better choice in your situation." Because the teacher asked to do it. It's just a exercise to helping a friend.

Answer (score 1):

your define is `float vector[0];`
you should change to `float vector[MAX_SIZE];`
or use `vector<float>`

when you use `float vector[0];` the `vetcor[0]`, `vector[1]` are actually on stack and will be overlapped later by other stack variables.